# Issue reading the properties using Annotation @Resource with the help of Spring Context

Tags: java, spring

ApplicationContext.xml

```
<beans>
 ....
<bean id="queueProperties"
      class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertiesFactoryBean">
    <property name="locations">
        <list>
            <value>classpath*:queueCredentials.properties</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
</beans>
```

JavaClass

```
public class TestBean{
    @Resource(name = "queueProperties")
    private Properties queueProperties;

    getPropertyValue(){
        queueProperties.getProperty("queueURL");
    }

}
```

enter code here

web.xml
     ....
     
        contextConfigLocation
        /WEB-INF/ApplicationContext.xml

```
 <listener>
    <listener-class>
        org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
    </listener-class>
 </listener>
 ...
```

While debugging the code noticed the Properties obj was not injected and shows as null, Tried with @Autowired and @Qualifier("queueProperties") but no luck.

Comment: You may need to specify in ApplicationContext.xml to scan for annotations. This would look something like the following if the context namespace is defined in the XML header: `<context:component-scan base-package="*" />`

Comment: namespace already applied like this  <context:component-scan base-package="com.*"/> also tried with what you suggested <context:component-scan base-package="*"/>, both doesn't give me what i want

Comment: Where do you use the TestBean?

Comment: TestBean is a simpleClass which needs the Properties obj, it can be called from any class in my package.

Comment: Do you have a TestBean _bean_. Spring has to be able to manage the object.

Comment: i don't have TestBean bean and i am not expecting the TestBean object also... all i want is the properties obj inside my TestBean class

Comment: Notice how @Resource is a Spring annotation. What does that tell you? How can Spring do anything if you dont have a bean? A bean is a Spring managed object.

Comment: The bean is already there right... org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertiesFactoryBean, i need the object of PropertiesFactoryBean in my TestBean Class, do i need to have the TestBean also in ApplicationContext.xml?

Answer (score 0):

Spring 3 you can directly read property by

```
@Value("${propertyName}")  
private String propertyField;
```

Properties can configure via XML as shown below :

```
<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer"
  p:location="classpath:queueCredentials.properties" id="propertyConfigurer"/>
```

If you have more than one properties files than see this [How to Configure more than one properties file](http://java.dzone.com/articles/using-more-one-property-file) in Spring 3.

**Another approach :**
configure a bean /  class that extend class `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer` and override `processProperties(ConfigurableListableBeanFactory beanFactoryToProcess,Properties props)` method to read all properties from file.

Here is example :

```
public class PropertyReader extends PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer
{  
   private static Map<String, String> propertiesMap;  

   @Override
   protected void processProperties(ConfigurableListableBeanFactory beanFactoryToProcess,Properties props)
   {  
      try{
            propertiesMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
            for (Object key : props.keySet()) {
                  String keyStr = key.toString();
                  propertiesMap.put(keyStr,props.getProperty(keyStr));
             }
          }
       catch(Exception ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
       }
   }  

   public static String getProperty(String name) {
           return propertiesMap.get(name);
   }

}
```

XML configuration :

```
<bean id="customerPropertyReader" class="PropertyReader">
    <property name="location" value="classpath:queueCredentials.properties"/>
</bean>
```

You can access any properties as shown below :

```
String propValue = PropertyReader.getProperty("queueURL");
```

Comment: i think it is not good idea to follow the second approach, because it is not just about the Properties, i have other bean creation which is also not working with @Resource annotation, searching if i am missing anything on the ApplicationContext.xml...

Comment: if i use any main function like this it is working fine, problem occurs only when  i use this in my web application (REST service) note: i have updated my web.xml to load the context  this is my main function code <b> ClassPathXmlApplicationContext xmlApplicationContext = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("/ApplicationContext.xml");
        Properties props = (Properties) xmlApplicationContext.getBean("queueProperties");</b>

Comment: my web.xml  <B>  <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/beans.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>
    
    <listener>
        <listener-class>
         org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
        </listener-class>
    </listener> </B>

Comment: Have you declare `TestBean` in xml ? are you getting any exception ? It works for me with same configuration.

Comment: i have not declared the TestBean in my context, in your case, how do you access the TestBean Class object?

Comment: I had declare bean in xml. i had also tried with code as you have mention in comments.